# R - tagging rows based on time intervals

Tags: r

I am working with some sales data and I need to tag each transaction based on the event during which the transaction happened. I have 2 dfs:

df1 with vector datetime containing a POSIXct datetime to the second of the transaction plus other untouched transaction data

| datetime | transaction.id |
| --- | --- |
| "2015-09-10 21:03:15 CDT" | "123abc" |
| "2015-09-12 20:59:13 CDT" | "345bcd" |

df2 with three vectors, event.name, start.time, and interval (a lubridate interval +- 2 hours of start.time, representing the time the store is open).

| event.name | start.time | interval |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "Event 1" | "2015-09-10 20:00:00 CDT" | 2015-09-10 18:00:00 CDT--2015-09-10 22:00:00 CDT |
| "Event 2" | "2015-09-12 20:00:00 CDT" | 2015-09-12 18:00:00 CDT--2015-09-12 22:00:00 CDT |

I have tried using dplyr mutate:

```
df1 %>% mutate(event.name = ifelse(datetime %within% df2$interval, df2$event.name, NA))
```

but that wants to apply the entire vector.

I've also tried using a left join, but it won't accept logicals for the by = argument

```
left_join(df1, df2, by = (df1$datetime %within% df2$interval))
```

Any ideas on how to apply the proper event tag to each transaction?

expected output:

| datetime | transaction.id | event.name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "2015-09-10 21:03:15 CDT" | "123abc" | "Event 1" |
| "2015-09-12 20:59:13 CDT" | "345bcd" | "Event 2" |

EDIT:
Thanks to everyone who helped out on this - I found that the best way to do it was event-wise with a while loop.

```
y <- 1

while (y < 1000)
{ x <- df2$event.name[y]
interval <- df2$interval[y]
temp2 <- df1$datetime %within% interval 
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate (temp = temp2)
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate (event.name = if_else(temp==TRUE, x, df2$event.name))
y = y + 1
}
```

It's pretty rough, but doing it this way allows for it to run on a massive scale while avoiding confusion around "near" matches (my dataset has 1000 events and 500k+ transactions. Hope this helps others!

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput` and expected output

Answer (score 1):

This data.table solution gets you close.

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
x <- data.table(
  datetime = as.POSIXct(
    c(
  "2015-09-10 21:03:15 CDT",
  "2015-09-12 20:59:13 CDT")
  ),
  transaction.id = 
    c("123abc", "345bcd"))
x[, start.time := datetime]
setkey(x, start.time)
y <- data.table(
  event.name = c("Event 1", "Event 2"),
  start.time = as.POSIXct(c(
    "2015-09-10 20:00:00 CDT", "2015-09-12 20:00:00 CDT"
  )),
  interval = c(
    "2015-09-10 18:00:00 CDT--2015-09-10 22:00:00 CDT",
    "2015-09-12 18:00:00 CDT--2015-09-12 22:00:00 CDT"
  )
)
y[, `:=`(
  start = as.POSIXct(str_remove(interval, "\\-{2}.*$")),
  end = as.POSIXct(str_remove(interval, "^.*\\-{2}")))][, 
  interval := NULL]
setkey(y, start, end)
x[y, roll = "nearest"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might like to try the `fuzzyjoin` package. You can use `fuzzy_left_join` with both data frames, using the start and end datetimes from the intervals.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(lubridate)

df2$start <- int_start(df2$interval)
df2$end <- int_end(df2$interval)

fuzzy_left_join(
  df1,
  df2,
  by = c("datetime" = "start", "datetime" = "end"),
  match_fun = c(`>=`, `<=`)
)
```